# Inherited from an itemsControl - How to change the type of the items?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listviewitem, itemspresenter

I'm trying to improve `ListView`. This mostly has to do with changed in the `ListViewItem` class. So I inherited from both, creating two costume controls:

```
NestedListView : ListView 
NestedListViewItem : ListViewItem
```

The problem is that now I want the `NestedListView`'s `<ItemsPresenter/>` to present `NestedListViewItem`s instead of regular `ListViewItems`. 
How do I achieve this?

(I pretty much have no idea **how** `<ItemsPresenter/>` works. So any explanation on that area could be helpful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the `GetContainerForItemOverride` method and return the type of item container you want:

```
public class NestedListView : ListView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new NestedListViewItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is NestedListViewItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Becareful, the accepted answer is not enough for a TreeView if you want all the descendants to be of the overriden TreeViewItem subclass.

Here is the complete solution:

1. Override the TreeViewItem class

```cs
public class TreeViewItemEx : TreeViewItem
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new TreeViewItemEx (); // Required to preserve the item type in all the hierarchy
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is TreeViewItemEx ;
    }
}
```

2. Override the TreeView class

```cs
public class TreeViewEx : TreeView 
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new TreeViewItemEx();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is TreeViewItemEx;
    }
}
```