# Best practice for dependency properties with reference type as default value

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, reference-type

I have the following DependencyProperty:

```
public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Items), typeof(ObservableCollection<ContentControl>), typeof(Group), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ContentControl>()));
```

Now as you can see giving it a reference type as a default value will only work once, as soon as i create a second instance of this class they will share that reference.

I could not find much about it and what the best way would be, anyone has a suggestion?

One way to do it would be to not give it a default value and set the reference with a new instance in the constructor:

```
public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Items), typeof(ObservableCollection<ContentControl>), typeof(Group));

public Group()
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<ContentControl>();
}
```

Comment: Best practice is not to set a default on a reference type dependency property. "what the best way would be" it is not clear to me from your question what you are trying to achieve.  You set values in xaml or bind to properties of viewmodels. If you have a reference type as a dependency property, then I'd expect the value to be coming from a viewmodel via binding

Comment: As a classic common example of a reference type dependency property I would point to datacontext. If it's set or inherited to anything, that'd be a viewmodel instance.

Comment: best practice will be using some ItemsControl as a base type of Group, and overriding GetContainerForItemOverride like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588248/inherited-from-an-itemscontrol-how-to-change-the-type-of-the-items

Comment: 1. it is unclear why this is a dependency property at all. If the property value is set by the Group control, it could as well be an ordinary readonly property. 2. When the property is settable, its type should not be ObservableCollection, but instead a more generic type like IEnumerable. You should check at runtime if the passed collection object implements INotifyCollectionChanged. 3. In case it is actually a dependency property, you could use SetCurrentValue to set its initial value in the constructor. You would thus not disable alternative value sources like Bindings or Styles Setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have figured out is the best practice as far as I am aware.

To quote from Microsoft's article [Collection-type dependency properties (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/collection-type-dependency-properties):

> When you create a dependency property, you typically specify the default value through dependency property metadata instead of specifying an initial property value. However, if your property value is a reference type, the default value should be set in the constructor of the class that registers the dependency property. The dependency property metadata shouldn't include a default reference-type value because that value will be assigned to all instances of the class, creating a singleton class.